# Paypal internal service error on 81251 on SetMobileCheckout call

Tags: paypal, checkout

I have SetExpressCheckout calling fine fine however when I attempt to call SetMobileCheckout I keep getting an error.

Any ideas on why I am getting this internal service error?

```
Array
(
[SMCFields] => Array
    (
        [phonecountrycode] => 
        [phonenum] => 
        [amt] => 20.00
        [currencycode] => USD
        [taxamt] => 
        [shippingamt] => 
        [desc] => $40.00 value at Il Bastardo
        [number] => 
        [custom] => 
        [invnum] => 
        [returnurl] => http://mydomain.com/checkout/review
        [cancelurl] => http://mydomain.com/checkout/cancel
        [addressdisplay] => 
        [sharephonenum] => 
        [email] => 
    )
```

Here is the response I receive on the call

```
Array
(
[ACK] => Failure
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 81251
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Internal Error
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Internal Service Error
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
[ERRORS] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [L_ERRORCODE] => 81251
                [L_SHORTMESSAGE] => Internal Error
                [L_LONGMESSAGE] => Internal Service Error
                [L_SEVERITYCODE] => Error
            )

    )

[REQUESTDATA] => Array
    (
        [USER] => sdk-three_api1.sdk.com
        [PWD] => QFZCWN5HZM8VBG7Q
        [VERSION] => 93.0
        [BUTTONSOURCE] => AngellEYE_PHPClass
        [SIGNATURE] => A-IzJhZZjhg29XQ2qnhapuwxIDzyAZQ92FRP5dqBzVesOkzbdUONzmOU
        [METHOD] => SetMobileCheckout
        [AMT] => 20.00
        [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
        [DESC] => $40.00 value at Il Bastardo
        [RETURNURL] => http://mydomain.com/checkout/review
        [CANCELURL] => http://mydomain.noo.com/checkout/cancel
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using SetMobileCheckout? That API call is beyond deprecated. Mobile Express Checkout has long since replaced it.